# I am pushing code to the forked repository. But, the PR goes to the upstream. Why?

Tags: github, pull-request, git-fork, upstream-branch

There is something that I do not understand.

1 - I am working on this repository `tallyfor/re-frame-firebase` ([link](https://github.com/tallyfor/re-frame-firebase)). As you see, it is a fork of `deg/re-frame-firebase` ([link](https://github.com/deg/re-frame-firebase)).

2 - Now, after doing a git clone of `git clone git@github.com:tallyfor/re-frame-firebase.git`. I have:

```bash
~/projects/re-frame-firebase

➜  git remote -v

origin  git@github.com:tallyfor/re-frame-firebase.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:tallyfor/re-frame-firebase.git (push)
```

Things seemed to be correct!

3 - So, I decided to create a branch called: `2-test` with one change:

[image]

After pushing to `origin` via magit, I have:

[image]

4 - On GitHub, again, things seemed to be correct, since the Pull Request possibility **appears on the forked repository**:

[image]

But, unfortunately, **after clicking** the button `Compare & Pull Request` on the forked repository, GitHub goes to the upstream repository:

[image]

I would like to push this code the forked repository, not the upstream one.

Why is that so? How can I fix this to have the desired behavior?

Comment: You should be able to select the fork if you click on the base repository. Configuring it so that the pull request defaults to the fork would probably be a good follow-up question.

Comment: Ok, thanks @chepner. Here is the follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74805402/how-to-configure-github-so-that-a-pull-request-to-a-forked-repository-uses-as-ba

Comment: Note: this is specific to GitHub (Bitbucket also has forks but they work just a little differently); the correct tag for GItHub and Bitbucket forks (and other Git-related forks) is [tag:git-fork] as [tag:fork] is for the Unix/Linux-style `fork` system call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner), the answer was selecting my organization forked repository as the `base`.